# Add FFT algorithm to android studio

Tags: java, android, import, fft

i found lot of FFT library on github but i don't know how to add them to my project.

I try to import it without success.

Can you help?

Here what i found:

1) https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms

2) https://github.com/wendykierp/JTransforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  your project has a libs folder for external dependencies then you are good. Else create one under the main project. If you have the jar with all [dependencies](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/github/wendykierp/JTransforms/3.1/JTransforms-3.1-with-dependencies.jar) for the FFT algorithm, put it in the above mentioned libs folder. Next open **build.gradle** under app and add the following line under **dependencies** if it not already there..:

`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Sync the project as you usually do.

Comment: Works great! Thank you